# How to write foreach with "&&" condition

Tags: c#, foreach

```
   foreach (Panel panelControls in PlaceControls.Controls.OfType<Panel>())
        {

   foreach (Panel panelControls in PlaceHolder1.Controls.OfType<Panel>())
        {

               //code here
        }
        }
```

I want to use "&&" condition between this two foreach loops like this:

```
foreach (Panel panelControls in PlaceControls.Controls.OfType<Panel>() 
&& Panel panelControls in PlaceHolder1.Controls.OfType<Panel>())
```

how can I use like this.

Comment: Please take the time to properly format your question.

Comment: It isn't clear what you want do to...

Comment: do you want to iterate through 2 lists in a single loop?

Comment: union the 2 lists somehow, like `PlaceControls.Controls.OfType().Union(PlaceHolder1.Controls.OfType()).ToList()`

Comment: @h3n perhaps it is `Concat` instead of `Union`... If thery are controls then there shouldn't be any big difference (because controls can be "child" only of one parent normally), but `Concat` is faster (doesn't check for uniqueness)

Comment: Actually i want to insert data from  created controls dynamically in this panel , but it inserted data two times

Answer (score 1):

You can't. `&&` is a logic operator.

`&&` is placed on a Boolean expression, while `foreach` iterate over `Collection` entity.

Comment: Actually i want to insert data from created controls dynamically in this panel , but it inserted data two times. then how can i use this loops so ,data will inserted only one times

Comment: The rule is: `Different question Different post.`